# How to check if any element has a class in jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

```js
$(".Button").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass("buttonActive")) {
        $(this).addClass("buttonActive");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("buttonActive");
    }
});
```

```css
.buttonActive {
    background: #100f10;
    color: white;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numberSelect">
  <button type="button" value="1" class="Button">1</button>
  <button type="button" value="2" class="Button">2</button>
  <button type="button" value="3" class="Button">3</button>
  <button type="button" value="4" class="Button">4</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="number" id="number">
</div>
```

What I wanna do is when I click on any button it checks if there is any other button has the class "buttonActive" and if any other button has this class it removes the class form the other button and add it to the button I clicked.
So it should always be a single button which has the "buttonActive" class.

Comment: Instead of that, you might be better of using [radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio), which already have this feature.

Comment: just use these lines `$(".Button").removeClass("buttonActive");$(this).addClass("buttonActive");`

Comment: You don't need to `e.preventDefault();` if it's a `type="button"` - there's nothing particular to prevent here.

Comment: Also there is build in function in jquery  to toggle class: https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: And to clarify, you don't need to "check if any button has the class then remove it" just remove it - if there's none with the class, nothing is done.  `$(".class").removeClass("class")`

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the class from all buttons first then add it to the clicked button like this:

```js
$(".Button").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass("buttonActive")) {
        $("button").removeClass("buttonActive");
        $(this).addClass("buttonActive");
    }
});
```

```css
.buttonActive {
    background: #100f10;
    color: white;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numberSelect">
  <button type="button" value="1" class="Button">1</button>
  <button type="button" value="2" class="Button">2</button>
  <button type="button" value="3" class="Button">3</button>
  <button type="button" value="4" class="Button">4</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="number" id="number">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to check the existence of a class by the `if { ... }` condition. This can be done in the jquery selector itself. Removing a class will affect only those selectors that contain this class, but not the current (this) selector:

```
...(".Button.buttonActive").not(this).removeClass("buttonActive");
```

There are several variations of the solution to your problem. But I want to offer a solution in one line, without conditions if.

```js
$(".Button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("buttonActive").closest("#numberSelect").find(".Button.buttonActive").not(this).removeClass("buttonActive");
});
```

```css
.buttonActive {
    background: #100f10;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numberSelect">
    <button type="button" value="1" class="Button">1</button>
    <button type="button" value="2" class="Button">2</button>
    <button type="button" value="3" class="Button">3</button>
    <button type="button" value="4" class="Button">4</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="number" id="number" />
</div>
```